# How to select input:text with specific value of specific attribute (maxlength)?

Tags: jquery

Need help with jQuery.

Here are some inputs in html:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="36">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="12">
```

I need to select one with maxlength="36" but no luck with

```
var mi = $('input:text[maxlength=36]');
```

Full src:

```
console.log('-- start --');
var inputs = $('input:text');
var i, myinput;
console.log(inputs.length);
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i]);
    if (inputs[i].maxLength == 36) {
        myinput = inputs[i];
        //break;
    }
}
console.log('-- myinput --');
console.log(myinput);
console.log('=============');
console.log('-- mi --');
var mi = $('input:text[maxlength=36]'); // <<<<<---need help here
console.log(mi);
console.log('-- end --');
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeXlO.png)

Answer (score 2):

CSS selector syntax should be: `$("input[type=text][maxlength=36]")`

```js
$("#log-value").on("click", () => {
    console.log($("input[type=text][maxlength=36]").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="36">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="12">

<button id="log-value">Log Value</button>
```

Comment: As far as i see the problem was "var mi = "
'input:text[maxlength=36]' works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the below methods can be used. One is by selector and the other uses find to find the input with attribute `maxlength=36`

```js
console.log($("input[type=text][maxlength=36]"))
console.log($(document).find($('input').attr('maxlength')=="36"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="36">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" class="v-textfield" maxlength="12">
```